# does the rate of change of height varies for different fluids?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I decided to experiment for the rate of flow of liquids (like water, oil, acid, etc) from a burette. I decided to use Torricelli's law $v=\sqrt{2gh}$. When experimenting, the time taken for a viscous liquid like oil took more time to empty out than less viscous like water. However the Torricelli's equation gives me the values of $dV/dt$ or $dH/dt$ (at a particular height) same for all liquids. But i think that this is wrong and that the rates shouldn't be the same. Am i wrong to think it this way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply Torricelli's equation with a coefficient called Discharge Coefficient:

There are varied approaches to this coefficient:

According to Mechanical Engineering Reference Manual Ninth Edition:
The maximum possible drain rate for a tank with a hole or tap at the base can be calculated directly from Bernoulli's equation, and is found to be proportional to the square root of the height of the fluid in the tank. This is Torricelli's law, showing that Torricelli's law is compatible with Bernoulli's principle. Viscosity lowers this drain rate. This is reflected in the discharge coefficient which is a function of the Reynold's number and the shape of the orifice.

According to Wikipedia, also the Discharge Coefficient can be estimated due to orifice size and fluid mass rate:
$C_d A = \dfrac{\dot{m}}{\sqrt{{2}{g_c}{\rho}{\Delta} {P}}}$

Where:
$C_d$ = Discharge Coefficient through the constriction (unit-less).
$A$ = Cross-sectional area of flow constriction (unit length squared).
$\dot{m}$ = Mass flow rate of fluid through constriction (unit mass of fluid per unit time).
${g_c}$ = Gravitational constant (Dimensionless).
$\rho$ = Density of fluid (unit mass per unit volume).
$\Delta P$ = Pressure drop across constriction (unit force per unit area).

In practice, I would estimate the coefficient constant by comparing your viscous flow versus water, to your particular application.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking at any system involving the flow of fluids there are two types of behaviour you need to consider, viscous and inertial.

- Viscous considerations arise from the thickness of the fluid. Obviously a thick fluid like oil takes more force to move than a thin fluid like water.
- Inertial considerations arise from the kinetic energy of the fluid. Moving fluid, like any other moving object, has kinetic energy and that energy can only have come from work done on the fluid, and work is fundamentally force times distance.

To illustrate this consider your burette. Imagine you could reduce the viscosity of the fluid to zero (maybe use superfluid helium). Would this mean the fluid flowed out of the burette infinitely fast? Obviously not, because that would mean the fluid had infinite kinetic energy, and that would require applying an infinite force to the fluid while the force available is just the pressure times the nozzle area. To work out how fast the zero viscosity fluid would flow you do a few sums equating potential and kinetic energy, and the result is ...

(pause for a roll on the drums ...)

... Toricelli's Law! If you look at the [Wikipedia article on Torricelli's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law) you'll see it works out the speed of the flow by equating the potential energy lost with the kinetic energy gained.

So Torricelli's law only applies when the system is dominated by inertial forces and viscous forces are small enough to be ignored i.e. at low viscosity and high pressure. That's why the viscosity of the fluid doesn't appear in the equation for the velocity. In your system the viscous forces are large compared to the inertial forces and Torricelli's law doesn't apply. The bad news is that calculating flow through an orifice can get a bit involved when viscosity is significant. From memory, if inertial forces can be ignored and the flow is laminar then the rate is inversely proportional to viscosity. However it was a long time ago I did this sort of stuff so check fro yourself rather than trusting my memory too far.